# Using awk to remove all lines of a multiple + 1

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a text file which is like:

```
header
p1
p2
p3
header
p4
p5
p6
header
p7
p8
p9
```

And I'd like to remove all the headers apart from the first one, so the results would be:

```
header
p1
p2
p3
p4
p5
p6
p7
p8
p9
```

I think this can be achieved by printing all the lines which aren't a multiple of 4, +1 (i.e. so don't print lines 4+1, 8+1, 12+1 etc). I know how to not print lines which are a multiple of 4:

```bsh
cat tmp2 | awk '{if((NR % 4 != 0)) {print $0}}'
```

But I am not sure how to make it so multiple of 4, +1, are not printed. I think the solution should be easy, but I am a bit stuck on how to get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do the arithmetic, probably I would do

```
awk 'NR==1 || (NR-1)%4' tmp2
```

since it makes the intent obvious.

Answer (score 1):

to remove header line appeared in any line except at first line:

```
awk 'NR==1 || !/header/' infile
```